# jquery touch punch and jquery ui 1.9.1

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I have been using jquery touch punch for a while and it has been perfect, until I updated to jquery ui 1.9.1 and jquery 1.8.3. It just does not seem to work. Is there a compatibility issue or something I have to do to make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: The odds of having the plugin author(s) answer your question directly are pretty low. Did you try their support forums? Otherwise, if you want us to help, you will have to tell us more about your problem, what the error is, if any, and update your question with the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when i was trying to use Jquery ui range slider along with touch punch to  provide support to touch devices.

As mentioned in the site [Touch punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com) , i added the below scripts in the same order, and was working fine, but when i shifted to jquery ui 1.9.2, it simply did not work.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

```
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

There was a dependency on two jquery ui core components - Widgets and Mouse. 
So i downloaded only those two UI Core components from [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/) renamed the custom download as ui-widget-mouse.js and included them before the touch punch, but after referring the jquery ui cusom js. This made the touch punch work fine for jquery-ui 1.9.2. 
I tested the same in iPad, iPad 2 and samsung galaxy tab 10inch. Was working fine wihout any issues.

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.1.9.min.js"></script> 

<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-widget-mouse.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
```